# How can I get the lowest value of a column in an array list and add it to a dictionary?

Tags: csv

I'm working on a piece of code that can open a csv file from python and work with the information it provides. This file is taken from a LeMans competition and contains, among other things, circuit sector times.
The file i work with is like this:
[CSV FILE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZhze.png) (Each column belongs to a certain information. In the rows the same team is repeated several times, but their times or other information are different)

At the moment I have made this code, but when I want to save the best times of each team, it saves the last ones or the ones that are not.

code:

```
def csv_reader ():
    correct = False
    while (not correct):
        try:
            filename=input("FileName.csv: ")
            f=open(filename, "r")
            csv_list = f.readlines()
            correct = True    
        except IOError:
            print("ERROR")
    f.close()
    return csv_list

def csv_data (csv_list):
    dictionary_1={}
    for line in csv_list: 
        data=line.split(';')
        team=data[0] 
        S1=(data[26])
        if team in dictionary_1:
            if dictionary_1[team][0]>S1:
                dictionary_1[team][0]=S1
        else:
            dictionary_1[team]=[0]
            dictionary_1[team][0]=S1
    return dictionary_1

csv_list = csv_reader()
del csv_list[0]

print (csv_data(csv_list))
```

I would like the code to read each row of a column and save, in this case, the smallest value for each team in a dictionary.

Thanks!

Comment: Post data as text here not not an external image.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard csv module?

Answer (score 0):

The image you provided doesn't really match your code (... vs field 26).  That said, adjusting it, it seem to works as expected.  Tweaked the code a bit:

```
def csv_data(csv_list, circuit_sect=26):
    dictionary_1 = {}
    for line in csv_list:
        data = line.split(';')
        team = data[0]
        S1 = float(data[circuit_sect].strip())
        if team not in dictionary_1 or dictionary_1[team] > S1:
            dictionary_1[team] = S1
    return dictionary_1


csv_list = [
        "1;...;36.067\n",
        "1;...;36.879\n",
        "10;...;37.768\n",
        "10;...;34.998\n"
]
print(csv_data(csv_list, 2))
```

and the output:

```
{'1': 36.067, '10': 34.998}
```